# How to link a remote git repo to a folder in another remote repo?

Tags: git, version-control

I have two separate Git repos:

- `MyTestCodeRepo`
- `MyProductCodeRepo`

I want to map the `MyTestCodeRepo` to a folder within `MyProductCodeRepo` (i.e. - `MyProductCodeRepo/MyTestCode`), so I can commit the product updates and related tests in one commit which will make it easier to manage them.

I read that git subtree is the way to go, but the Git version I use (2.6.3) does not support it. I read [here](https://www.atlassian.com/blog/git/alternatives-to-git-submodule-git-subtree) that subtree is available from stock version of Git since May 2012 – v1.7.11 and above, but strangely my Git installation does not identify subtree command.

1. What is the best way to obtain the above requirement in Git?
2. Is subtree the way to go? If so, do I have to install a separate module or something to obtain subtree support?

EDIT: When I tried to use `subtree` this is the output I get.

```
grom> git subtree add
git: 'subtree' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
grom> git --version
git version 2.6.3
```

Comment: You can use [git-submodule](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-submodule.html), [git-subtree](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git/plain/contrib/subtree/git-subtree.txt) or [git-subrepo](https://github.com/ingydotnet/git-subrepo). On some platforms you might need to follow the installation instructions to install `git-subtree`.

Comment: Yes, `git subtree` is the closer way for your situation. And `git subtree` is available for git 2.6.3, so what do you mean it's not support? What's the output if you use the command like `git subtree add --prefix=MyTestCode <URL for MyTestCodeRepo> master`? Or what if you update the git version?

Comment: @Marina-MSFT: When I issued the command I get the above error (I have added it as an edit).

Comment: Found a nice guide on git submodule here: https://chrisjean.com/git-submodules-adding-using-removing-and-updating/

Comment: @Sampath It seems the version 2.6.3 is not the version for git bash. You can install git bash https://git-scm.com/downloads, and then `git subtree` commands can be used.

Comment: @Sampath BTW, if you already add the testcode repo by git submodule, you can add an answer and accept it. It will also benefit others who have similar questions.